# Dynamically load an object c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, dynamic, load

I have a asp.net project, and in my design page I have some `asp:Label` objects with names like aLabel0, aLabel1, aLabel2...aLabel9. If I don't want to create them dynamically from my aspx.cs page and add them to a container like an `asp:Panel`, is there any way to load them dynamically from the aspx page to aspx.cs page?

Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Label tempLabel = LoadDynamically("aLabel" + i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why not add them in your code behind (aspx.cs)?

Comment: I have some asp controls (labels-textboxes-literals) in panels and i want to repeat them and call them from javascript(using ClientID). It is more appropriate το create them dynamically but i found it easier to add them in my aspx form. My problem were the too many lines of code to write foreach control in the code behind to add the javascript events(using the aLabel0.Attributes.Add(eventName, eventFunction) Method). The answer for my query is the FindControl method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Control.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)

```
var label = panel.FindControl( "aLabel" + i.ToString() ) as Label;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for an asp:Repeater.  If you feel you have to (you dont) you can define the data source of the repeater in aspx as well.  Then just create in your  the label with respective values injected

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to dynamically create controls you can do something like so:

```
Label lb = new Label();
lb.ID = "aLabel0";
lb.Text = "I'm label #0";
Page.Controls.Add(lb);
```

The first three lines create the label and the last line adds it to the container. In this case I used `Page` but you can use any container control.